# How to properly fall FORWARD while ice skating and prevent wrist fractures?

Tags: technique, injuries, ice-skating

I've looked this up everywhere and cannot find a good answer.

In ice skating, they teach us to fall to the side or on our bottoms to prevent injury. However, what do you do when you're about to fall forward? e.g. tripping over your ice pick for figure skaters. My instinct would be to extend my arms to break the fall. This will likely hurt my wrists, if not fracture it. Is there a proper technique?

Comment: They teach you to fall to your side, because that's the proper technique to fall.  When your ice pick catches, you still can rotate your body some so you fall on your side rather than on your front, no?

Answer (score 2):

You will almost always have a slight rotation one direction or the other, and even if you don't, you can use whichever foot has best contact with the ice to start a twist as you fall.

Then rotate your shoulders, wrapping your arms in to speed the spin as needed, so you can take the fall sideways, rolling rather than impacting.

Answer (score 0):

Use your underarms, not your hands to break your fall. Turn away your head so you don't crash facefirst into the ice if your arms slide away to the sides.